# same type action filter on controller and its action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have defined an action filter like this:

```
public class InvokeConditionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private ConditionRule conditionRule;

    public InvokeConditionAttribute(ConditionRule conditionRule)
    {
        this.conditionRule = conditionRule;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // check condition rule
    }
}
```

ConditionRule in parameter is a enum type.
then i create a controller like below:

```
[InvokeCondition(ConditionRule.Condition1, Order = 1)]
public class AttendanceModificationController : Controller
{
    [InvokeCondition(ConditionRule.Condition2, Order = 2)]
    public ActionResult SomeAction()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

problem is method level filter not invoke.

can define same filter type with different parameter in asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decorate your action filter with the [`AttributeUsage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute and specify the `AllowMultiple = true`:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class InvokeConditionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    ...
}
```

Now your `OnActionExecuting` method will be triggered twice for the `SomeAction` action.